# Python - Only the first inner funciton was excuted

Tags: python, function, schedule

I am writing a program that could greet users on at fixed times. And if the user didn't reply anything within a period of time, the program will send another message.

Currently I use a outer function including two inner functions as I wanted to import the outer one into another main file in the future. But when I call the outer function test(), only the first inner function weekends() was executed.

This is my code.

```
import schedule
import time
from threading import Thread

def test():

    def weekends():
        weekends_ans = None
        def weekends_check():
            time.sleep(20)
            if weekends_ans!=None:
                return
            print('\nWhat about watching a movie?')
        Thread(target=weekends_check).start()
        weekends_ans=input('Whats your plan for weekends?')

    def monday():
        monday_ans = None
        def monday_check():
            time.sleep(20)
            if monday_ans!=None:
                return
            print('\nHave fun next week!')
        Thread(target=monday_check).start()
        monday_ans=input('Monday again.')

    schedule.every().friday.at('17:00').do(weekends)
    schedule.every().sunday.at('17:00').do(monday)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

test()
```

Anyone could help?

Comment: Sidenote: Compare agains `None` with `if weekend_ans is not None` instead of the `!=` operator

Comment: Thanks, but it doen't work..

Answer (score 0):

Does it enter this part

`if weekends_ans!=None:
    return`

If it does the code will return and will not contine to the next part.
( It will do a return and then continue from below test() )

Side note: Check out async programming. Using sleep is almost always bad practise, example link to async:
https://hackernoon.com/asynchronous-python-45df84b82434

Comment: Thanks, I read through the article of async and the library document but I still have no clue how to implement the program with async. Could you please give me an example using async that can achieve the same functionality?